# How do you clear out the sorting icons in ngx-datatable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ngx-datatable

I'm using ngx-datatable with Angular 5.0 and am implementing sorting with externalSorting set to true as I am doing server side pagination and sorting in the backend. I have a button that on click, resets the data in the table to the data that is displayed on load, so that when a bunch of sorting is done, the user can reset to the original view. It works as intended, however I don't know how to clear out the sorting icons in the column header. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution ended up being creating a reference to the ngx-datatable element, and setting the sorts array to a blank array.

Example HTML:

```
<ngx-datatable #table
   class="material"
   [columns]="cols"
   [rows]="rows"
>
```

And TypeScript:

```
@ViewChild(DatatableComponent) table: DatatableComponent;

reset() {
    this.table.sorts = [];
}
```